# Find corresponding data in Sheet 1 based on data on Sheet 2 and transfer secondary data to Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro whereby I am able to do the following:

1. Based on values in Cells of Column B in Sheet 1:

   a. Search for same corresponding value in Sheet 2 in Column B

   b. Transfer data in Column Z in Sheet 1 to Column Z in Sheet 2 of the row of the searched corresponing value

   c. If search for corresponding value returns nothing, go to next cell in Column B in Sheet 1 and repeat till last cell in Column in Sheet 1.

Following is the code that I have created so far, however it does not transfer the data.

```
Sub TransferDataMaster(rw)
Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For rw = 2 To LastRow
If Range("B" & rw).Value = "AA" Then Application.Run "TransferData", "AA" rw
If Range("B" & rw).Value = "BB" Then Application.Run "TransferData", "BB", rw
Next rw

End Sub

--------------------------------------------

Sub TransferData(Arg1, rw)

   DataValue = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("Z" & rw).Value

   Sheets("Sheet 2").Activate
   Range("B2:B1000").Find(CStr(Arg1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
   DTRW = ActiveCell.Row
   Range("Z" & DTRW).Value = CStr(DataValue)

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any advise or assistance. Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: What is your code doing? What did you accomplish so far? At what step are you stuck? Avoid using `.activate` as much as possible, assign your worksheets to variables instead. Update your question accordingly. As soon as you tell us your exact problem we will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi David. I apologize if my question lacked clarity. I am new to excel macro coding and learning as I go. The macro that I am creating is to transfer data from Column Z in Sheet 1 to Column Z in Sheet 2 based on values in Column B of Sheet 1, and to go accordingly to the next row after the previous row is completed with the transfer. The code I have created so far executes but it does not transfer the data to the desired column and I am not sure which part of the code to correct or is the code wrong in general.

Comment: Start with a smaller example. Try these things in a separate document: `1.` transfer data from one cell to another. `2.` transfer data between sheets. `3.` construct a loop. If you get stuck with any of there things, update your question accordingly, do not post it as a comment. With these skills down you can easily solve the above problem. Ask here if you get stuck with any of these things!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VLOOKUP formula in Column Z in sheet 2:

- Lookup Value - Cells of column B in sheet 2
- Table Array - Range of B:Z from sheet 1
- Col_index_num - Number of columns it is to column Z from B in Sheet 1
- Range Lookup - False